Is there a way to render gt tables as PNGs with (a) no browser and (b) without wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage? (R/Python)
I have a really pretty gt table that we'd like to automate production of. Running this on our remote server has some limitations: enterprise policy is that no browsers, headless or otherwise, may be installed on the server; the admin has been unwilling to install wkhtmltopdf.
So I can either run this locally, which I'd rather avoid, or I can schedule it to crank out an HTML table, which is a pain for the person who actually uses these images. Rendering the gt_tbl using ggplot destroys a lot of the formatting that was done.
The R script that generates the table is set up now to output an html table. I'm open to solutions in R or Python that can run after the table is generated.
Thanks!

If you want something that parses and renders an HTML table that can't be a web browser of any kind, I'm not sure such a thing exists. Especially if you are using a bunch of fancy CSS styling. I can't think of any reason someone would build a tool like that. is gt really a requirement? It sounds ill-suited to your actual use case.

@MrFlick I suspect that you're right on both counts - trying to productionalize something that was built without it in mind, and I'll almost certainly end up redoing it. Figured I'd drop a line in the water here just in case!

Figured it out!
foo <- <a gt_tbl object>

library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotify)
library(rsvg) #required to render SVG cells

foo_1 <- as_gtable(foo)
foo_2 <- as.ggplot(foo_1)
ggsave('path/to/file.png', foo_2)

